# Undo checkout using cleartool

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

How to undo checkout an element using cleartool command line tool in clearcase?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
cleartool unco /path/to/element
```

See the [`cleartool uncheckout` man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_uncheckout.htm)

You have two options possible:

```
–kee/p
```

> Preserves the contents of the checked-out version under a file-name of the form element-name.keep (or, to prevent name collisions, `element-name.keep.1`, `element-name.keep.2`, and so on).

```
–rm
```

> Does not preserve the contents of the checked-out version. Thus, any edits that had been made to the checked-out version are lost.